# What is this type of form/element called?

Tags: forms

I should know this, but I'm drawing a complete blank...

## What is this type of form called?

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any of such type for html form. Probably you can use available jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has a name. It's a multiselect `select` element customized with a jQuery plugin

See http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_create_add_remove_select_list.htm

or http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next/

etc

Comment: **Multiselect**! Thanks - it's been a long day. [What I couldn't remember](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple)